# change java variables from JRuby code?

Tags: java, variables, jruby

As title says i whant to change my variables in java from my jruby code

To be more specific i have an integer in my Java code which has no value yet, And i whant with my JRuby code give this variable an value, But i have no idea how to do this.

This is how far i got with the JRuby code..

```
require 'java'
puts "Set player health here"
playerHealth = 3 # Setting player health here!
```

But have not yet wrote anything in java.  This is pretty much all I have so far..

Comment: Check this out. http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/CallingJavaFromJRuby. For example >> java.lang.System.setProperty "myprop", "123"
=> nil
>> java.lang.System.getProperty "myprop"
java.lang.System.getProperty "myprop"
=> "123"

Comment: Do you plan to call java from jruby, or call jruby from java?  Also, why have different components messing with eachothers variables?  That's probably not a good idea even within a single language.  Why not set your variable with the return value from a method call?

Comment: I don't know how to do that either..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, you are trying to invoke the JRuby engine from Java, so you could do something like this to modify a Java variable in JRuby:

```
import javax.script.*;

public class EvalJRubyScript {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();

        int playerHealth = 0;

        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("jruby");
        ScriptContext context = engine.getContext();
        context.setAttribute("playerHealth", playerHealth, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);

        try {
            engine.eval("$playerHealth = 42");
            playerHealth = (Integer)context.getAttribute("playerHealth",  ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);

            System.out.println(playerHealth);
        } catch (ScriptException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in the script `playerHealth` is a global variable.

Check out [this link](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/) for more details if you want to load an external JRuby script rather than evaluating code.